# Multiple react apps in a single page and keep them in sync

Tags: javascript, reactjs, server-rendering

I have e-commerce based page. The entire page is not wrapped within a single react app.

The bulk of the page's static content is rendered on the server-side using EJS. Upon rendering on the client we initialize two isolated react apps with their own states.

- Cart App. (Shows a count representing items count in the cart)
- Product list app - The product list app renders a list of products.

Each product item has an **Add to Cart** button. When the user clicks on it we need to immediately update the count in the cart without refreshing the page.

Now the question I have is if there is a way to achieve this without rendering the entire page in react. Below is the rough HTML markup I have.

```
<navbar>
    <navbar-links/>
    <div id="site-cart-app"></div> // this is where the cart react app is initialized.
</navbar>
<div id="product-list-app"></div> // this is where the product list app is initialized.
```

Comment: It may have changed, but multiple apps on a single page calling for hooks may reject with some errors

Answer (score 2):

High-level summary - 
To make sync multiple React app on a single page you need a common data source, like `REDUX` (I personally recommend) and `subscribe` to the `REDUX Store` in multiple React app and update component accordingly.

How to achieve? (What I did with my project)

1. Create 2 separate react-redux applications.
2. Make Common store and bundle code and run.

This seems simple but ain't.

The problem which I faced during implementation.

How to separate React projects with common Redux Store and reducers.
- For this, I used [Redux-Dynamic-Modules](https://redux-dynamic-modules.js.org/) library which allows us to make a separate store or load reducers on a load of a component.

I'm still working on it but for your ref. [Here is my git repo](https://github.com/sunilnkashyap/skdroid-poc) for a similar problem.

Answer (score 2):

## You can solve these multiple ways,

One of them, you add a service where you write the code request for Add or Remove card item and use Rxjs Subject and Subscribe from card component example here.

**In your Services.js**

```
import { Observable, Subject } from "rxjs";
export class CardService {
   public static observable = new Subject();
}
```

**In your productpage**

```
import { CardService  } from ./services/CardService";

//trigger when click to add or remove Card item 
TollAdminService.observable.next({ cardItem, action });
```

**And in your card component**

```
import { CardService  } from ./services/CardService";

// inside the component constructor like this
constructor(props) {
    TollAdminService.observable.subscribe((cardItem: any, action: any) => {
      //add your action code here...
    }
}
```

### May be it helps you to solve your problem

**Thanks**

Answer (score 1):

you can use common redux store to maintain the cart count, both Apps will use that store

Comment: is there some online reference or an example I can look into?

Comment: Look into this https://redux.js.org/recipes/isolating-redux-sub-apps